Decoding unique timestamp format in SQLite database
I'm trying to interface with Things 3's SQLite database and have come across a timestamp that I can't find a standard for.
Some of the values stored and their corresponding dates:
131141760 - 1/1/2001
131731584 - 1/1/2010
132059264 - 1/1/2015
132649088 - 1/1/2024
Oddly, other data in the table is stored as UNIX timestamps (i.e. 1724349077.57524) so I'm not sure why this data is different. Maybe they are using some non-standard epoch?
I've tried offsetting the values to align them with a standard epoch but their offsets all vary. If it's helpful, I can provide the database or additional dates. I reached out to Things support and they just told me the values were UNIX, but the dates are way off and they don't align with UNIX or Cocoa Core Data conversions.

This is odd. From the given values, the value increases by 65536 per year. Can you post the value for another month, like 1 Feb 2001 and 1 Nov 2001 for example?

It looks like a custom bit packed format. My guess is: year = value >> 16; month = (value >> 12) & 0b1111; day = (value >> 7) & 0b11111 but I'll need some values for other months and dates to confirm.

That appears to be (year65536)+(month4096)+(day*128)

Here are some additional dates:
132649088 - Jan 1 2024,
132653184 - Feb 1 2024,
131150208 - March 3 2001,
132609920 - July 15 2023,
131145856 - Feb 1 2001

The value you have seems to be a bitwise encoding of year / month / day. Based on the examples you've provided, they can be decoded like this:
with x(value) as (
  values (131141760), (131731584), (132059264), (132649088), (132653184), (131150208), (132609920)
)
select
  value,
  (value / 65536) as year,
  ((value / 4096) % 16) as month,
  ((value / 128) % 32) as day
-- or using bitwise operators
--  value >> 16 as year,
--  ((value >> 12) & 15) as month,
--  ((value >> 7) & 31) as day
from x;

Output:
value,year,month,day
131141760,2001,1,1
131731584,2010,1,1
132059264,2015,1,1
132649088,2024,1,1
132653184,2024,2,1
131150208,2001,3,3
132609920,2023,7,15

Explanation:
132609920 =

111111001110111011110000000 in binary =

11111100111 0111 01111 0000000
^ year      ^ mo ^ day
= 2023         7    15

